# can't connect printer m2070fw to chromebook.

Tags: wireless-networking

I received a cd to connect my printer to my chromebook.  Needed a host computer because I don't have a cd port.
Took it to my daughter's house, she set it up after 1 1/2 hours and it printed out a page.  I brought it home, and now it tells me that the printer is off line.  The printer is wps synced to the netgear router.  Why? How? What?  Samsung helpline is worthless.  They keep sending me back to the same blessed "help" page, which does nothing.
I tried the ip address syncthru web service which was worthless because it just tells me there is no such page as the ip address the help page tells me to go to.

I have a chromebook.  Does that mean I have a chrome browser?
I am so frustrated and so lost now I don't know what to do.

Answer (score 0):

It probably says printer is offline because that was the printer at your daughter's house, if I'm reading correctly.

Chromebooks run on ChromeOS, so you don't *just* have the browser.

Your printer is a [**cloud print ready**](http://www.google.com/cloudprint/learn/printers.html#info-samsung) printer according to Google, so you should try to setup your printer using [**Samsung's Cloud Print instructions**](http://www.samsung.com/us/support/answer/ANS00038562/238395) which will hook your printer up to your Google account.

According to Google, once a printer is in CloudPrint:

> The printer is now associated with your Google Account and connected to Google Cloud Print. You can print to this printer whenever you’re signed in with the same Google Account on your Chromebook.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread but I was dealing with a similar problem which I just solved.

My Samsung M2070FW suddenly stopped being able to connect to my WiFi router after I installed OpenWRT and I couldn't figure out why until today. It suddenly dawned on my that when I flashed the new firmware I also renamed the wireless networks. The new name included a space character which not all devices can handle. I replaced the spaces in the name with a period and an underscore and the device connected again without a hitch.

Hope this helps someone down the road!